# How do I save student attendance project data?

Tags: python, sql, mysql, database, local-storage

(I use Google Translator)

I want to create a student attendance project using Python. I did not know the appropriate way to save the data for this project. The way of arranging data that I think about is as follows. There is a set of materials inside each material set of groups, and inside each group is a set of dates, and inside each date is student attendance at this date.

I designed the interface (using Tkinter), and I created a JSON file as a project data file using the way I explained to save the data for this project, but I had a problem with saving attendance, so I decided to change it.

**all I want**

**1- What do I use to save data for such projects? database right? (I do not know how to use it in the same complicated way that I want, and I did not find an explanation similar to what I want when I search )**

**2- I am a beginner in arranging project data, and I do not mind suggesting a better way to arrange this project data**

This is a gif of how the project works:

[click me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COa1Y.gif)

and this is a JSON file:

[click me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm3ze.png)

Comment: Relational (SQL-style) databases organize data into tables. Each table holds as many rows as needed to hold the application data. Each row has a programmer-defined fixed set of columns (or fields), each of a fixed data type. Relational databases are  generally unsuitable for holding nested data structures like the one you mentioned, unless you work out a way to convert the data when you read it from and write it to the database.I suggest you work through a few tutorials on using Python with MySQL or some other database to get a feel for how this works, then revisit your data design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be 2 ways to persist your data.

1. SQL Database - like mysql, oracale sql, postgresSQL etc.
2. NoSQL - json or document based mongoDB can work for you.

I assume you are a student or a learner and trying to learn how to build apps like these.

You can start of with learning the SQL approach to store your data.

**First thing:**

You can do is follow some documentation and try to connect to a database from a simple python application.

A very simple documentation is present over here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp

As the page says, you need to install the mysql database on your machine first.
Then you need a mysql connector for your app.
That connector can be imported in python file and it can be used to connect to database.

Create a database schema and a [sample test table](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_create_table.asp) for learning.

You can play around with it and try to perform some CRUD operations using the connector.

C - [Create a record](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp) (insert query)

R - [Retrieve a record](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_select.asp) (select query)

U - [Update a record](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_update.asp) (update query)

D - [Delete a record](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_delete.asp) (delete query)

**Second Thing:**

You need to create a schema of how you will store your attendance data in table format.

For example you can have tables as below
Table for Groups(id, group name)
Table for Student (id, name, and some more information if needed)
Table for Attendance (date, group_id, student_id, present)

These are just examples, you can design your schema according to your data.
And then normalize it more if it can be.([Read about Normalizing tables](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html))

Once you are done with SQL approach you can try to move on to NoSQL approach for learning purpose as well !

All the best.